# How to implement restart or exit options

Tags: c#, windows

I'm quite new to programming just started about 3 days ago. I am very proud of what I made, a "Guessing Game" that's pretty basic and straightforward no random characters or anything. And since I'm fairly new to loops. I want to have an option after the game that shows 2 options either to restart the game or to exit. And I can't wrap my head around it.

Here is my code.

```cs
using System;

namespace Basics_Guessing_Game_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string winningWord = "Rastaman";
            string guess = "";
            int guessCount = 0;
            int guessLimit = 3;
            int guesses = 3;
            bool outOfGuesses = false;

            while (guess != winningWord && !outOfGuesses)
            {

                if (guessCount < guessLimit)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t--------You have " + guesses + " guess/guesses left--------");
                    Console.Write("Enter your guess: ");
                    guess = Console.ReadLine();
                    guessCount++;
                    if (guess != winningWord)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t--------Incorrect Word!--------");
                        guesses--;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    outOfGuesses = true;
                }
            }
            if (outOfGuesses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\n\t--------Out of guesses :(--------");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\n\t====------**Congrats you win!**------====");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easiest to just wrap everything inside yet another do-while loop

Comment: @Martheen Thank you. I just solved my problem thanks to your suggestion <3.